# AlarmManager not working on Asus ZenFone 2 devices with Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Is there anyone experiencing the issue with AlarmManager on Asus devices? I've developed an app that is a reminder and needs to fire at exact time. I'm using `AlarmManager.setExact()` for all pre-Marshmallow devices and `AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` in Android 6.0+ but still get bad reviews from Zenfon users. Ie. today I've got 1* rating from the user of ZenFone 2 Laser (ZE500KL) (ASUS_Z00E_2) :(

The same is with:

- ZenFone 2 (ZE550ML) (Z008_1)
- ZenFone 2 (ZE500CL) (ASUS_Z00D)
- ZenFone 2 (ZE551ML) (Z00A)

Good news is that is works in on:

- ZenFone 5
- ZenFone 6

Seems like guys from IBM had the same problem: http://www.asus.com/zentalk/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=70396

Does anyone of you challenged the same problem and have any solution for that?

Comment: you can also try with this method for setting alarm setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, PendingIntent operation) check documentation.Also use WakefulBroadcast receiver when alarm will be triggered.

Comment: As I've read using setAlarmClock causes displaying additional icon in the status bar, right?

Comment: yes it will show but alarm may work

Comment: Someone on ASUS forum suggested that it may be connected with this vendor's power management solution called Auto-Start Manager. I let affected users know and will update this thread as soon as i get any update from them.

Answer (score 1):

after some time I see results and it was exactly the point.

All you need to do is to let your users know to get to AUTO-START MANAGER in Settings and allow your app. That works fine for me.